# Find closest #loading and display it?

Tags: javascript, html, modal-dialog, loading

I have some code from another question that shows loading for a few seconds using:

```
  const Loading = () => {
    let tOut = null;
    const el = document.querySelector(".loading");
    const show = () => {
      el.classList.add('show');
      tOut = setTimeout(hide, 5000);
    };  
    const hide = () => {
      el.classList.remove('show');
      clearTimeout(tOut);
    };
    return {
      show,
      hide
    };
  };


  const loadingDots = Loading();
  const loadBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.item');

  [...loadBtns].forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', loadingDots.show));
```

Only issue is I need it to display when I open 3 seperate modals, but only the modal closest to the top of the page shows the loading screen, I have a feeling it's because it's not displaying the **closest** #loading screen and instead displaying the first one it finds, the html for #loading is:

```
 <div id="loading"><i></i><i></i><i></i></div>
```

it's injected in the page using php so this same code shows up in 3 places (not sure if that could have anything to do with it).

[image: how modal 1 looks on click]
[image: how modal 2 looks on click]

The HTML is:

```html
<div class="services_bg_images">
  <div class="services_container" ID='services-target'>
    <div class="services_title_main">
      <h6 data-aos="fade-down">Our Capabilities</h6>
    </div>
    <div data-aos="fade-down" class="underline4"></div>
    <div class="services_text">
      <p data-aos="fade-down" class="p3">Click modules to book & view prices where available.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="services_wrap">

      <div class="items">
        <div class="item" id="capa_1" data-modal="#modalFive">
          <div class="services_title">
            <h1 data-aos="fade-right" data-aos-offset="40">Example</h1>
          </div>
          <div data-aos="fade-left" class="underline3"></div>
          <div class="Services-paragraph">
            <p data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-duration="400" class="p4">

              </p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="modalFive" class="modal_briefs">
          <div class="inline-wrap"><span class="closex_brief"></span>

            <div class="brief_container_modal">
             <div class="loading"><i></i><i></i><i></i></div>
              <div class="capabilities_title_main">
                <h6 data-aos="fade-down">Get a Quote</h6>
              </div>
              <div data-aos="fade-down" class="underline4"></div>
              <div class="capabilities_text">
                <p data-aos="fade-down" class="p3">Fill in the brief below to get a quote.</p>
              </div>
              <div class="brief_wrap_modal">
                <iframe id="brief_1" data-src="/wordpress/gfembed/?f=5" height="100%" width="100%" frameBorder="0" scolling="no" class="gfiframe"></iframe>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>


        <div class="item" id="capa_2" onclick="location.href='pricing';">
          <div class="services_title">
            <h1 data-aos="fade-right" data-aos-offset="40">Example</h1>
          </div>
          <div data-aos="fade-left" class="underline3"></div>
          <div class="Services-paragraph">
            <p data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-duration="800" class="p4">

              </p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="item" id="capa_3" data-modal="#modalSeven">
          <div class="services_title">
            <h1 data-aos="fade-right" data-aos-offset="40">Example</h1>
          </div>
          <div data-aos="fade-left" class="underline3"></div>
          <div class="Services-paragraph">
            <p data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-duration="1200" class="p4">

             </p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="modalSeven" class="modal_briefs">
          <div class="inline-wrap"><span class="closex_brief"></span>

            <div class="brief_container_modal">
             <div class="loading"><i></i><i></i><i></i></div>
              <div class="capabilities_title_main">
                <h6 data-aos="fade-down">Get a Quote</h6>
              </div>
              <div data-aos="fade-down" class="underline4"></div>
              <div class="capabilities_text">
                <p data-aos="fade-down" class="p3">Fill in the brief below to get a quote.</p>
              </div>
              <div class="brief_wrap_modal">
                <iframe id="brief_3" data-src="/wordpress/gfembed/?f=3" height="100%" width="100%" frameBorder="0" scolling="no" class="gfiframe"></iframe>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>


        <div class="item" id="capa_4" data-modal="#modalEight">
          <div class="services_title">
            <h1 data-aos="fade-right" data-aos-offset="40">Example</h1>
          </div>
          <div data-aos="fade-left" class="underline3"></div>
          <div class="Services-paragraph">
            <p data-aos="fade-up" data-aos-duration="1600" class="p4">

              </p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div id="modalEight" class="modal_briefs">
          <div class="inline-wrap"><span class="closex_brief"></span>
            <div class="brief_container_modal">
             <div class="loading"><i></i><i></i><i></i></div>
              <div class="capabilities_title_main">
                <h6 data-aos="fade-down">Get a Quote</h6>
              </div>
              <div data-aos="fade-down" class="underline4"></div>
              <div class="capabilities_text">
                <p data-aos="fade-down" class="p3">Fill in the brief below to get a quote.</p>
              </div>
              <div class="brief_wrap_modal">
                <iframe id="brief_4" data-src="/wordpress/gfembed/?f=4" height="100%" width="100%" frameBorder="0" scolling="no" class="gfiframe"></iframe>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.loading {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1000;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  display:flex;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 3em;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content:center;
  visibility: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.4s;
}
.loading.show {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
}
@keyframes blink {
  50% {opacity: 1;}
}
.loading i:after {content: "\25cf";}
.loading i { opacity: 0; animation: blink 1.2s infinite; }
.loading i:nth-child(2) { animation-delay: .2s; }
.loading i:nth-child(3) { animation-delay: .4s; }

.brief_container_modal {
    position: absolute;
}
.brief_container,.brief_container_modal{
    z-index:99;
    top:150px;
    width:1200px;
    max-width:90%;
    margin-bottom:50px;
    left:0;
}
.brief_container,.brief_container_modal,
.brief_wrap_modal,.closex_brief {
    margin-right:auto;
    margin-left:auto;
    right:0
}
.brief_container_modal{
    background:linear-gradient(to bottom right,#f5f5f5 50%,#fff 50%);
    border:3px solid #ec321f;
    border-radius:10px;
}
.closex_brief{
    position:absolute;
    background:url(IMAGES/close_icon.png);
    background-size:50px 50px;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    display:block;
    left:0;
    top:125px;
    z-index:1000
}
.brief_wrap_modal {
    position: relative;
    width: 1150px;
    max-width: 95%;
    height: inherit;
}
```

If anyone can help would appreciate!

Comment: Why don't use jQuery? `.find()` would make it easy :)

Comment: ah ye, could you put it in the code so I can see? guessing you mean instead of queryselector?

Comment: IDs are supposed to be unique. You can't have more than one `#loading` DIV. Use a class and `querySelectorAll()` if you want to have more than one.

Comment: @Barmar has a point there, you should use classes.

Comment: Could you put it in context of the code? so you mean querySelectorAll("#loading"); would fix the issue?

Comment: The problem is actually with `querySelectorAll('#capa_1')`.

Comment: I know about not using non-unique Id's just put the code I was given in another question, i've changed the code to match my classes instead of ID's.

Comment: changed to .item but still only works for the first modal and not the other 2 modals, all modals have the class .item so it should work but I think it keeps trying to activate the first #loading it finds instead of looking for the one closest?

Answer (score 1):

IDs are supposed to be unique. Therefore, `document.querySelectorAll('#capa_1')` only selects the first modal with that ID. Use a class to match all the modal DIVs.

In fact, you only have one DIV with `id="capa_1"`. All the modals have `class="item"`, so you should use that to get them all.

The JS should be:

```
const loadBtns = document.querySelectorAll('.item');
```

Comment: the div that contains the id="capa_1" also has a class of ".item" so I linked to that but it doesn't work, only works with the id for some reason?

Comment: Elements can have multiple classes, they shouldn't interfere. I've shown how to do it in the answer.

Comment: It works for the first modal but not the other 2 still, all the modals have the class .item so it should work? I think it's not finding the closest #loading and instead keeps activating the first one but not sure, if you need a link to the site I can provide if it helps

Comment: There can only be one `#loading`. But they're all the same, so why does it matter which one it activates?

Comment: it's only showing on first modal, the second and third look like the second picture in my question, no #loading screen shows up, I'm gonna try move where I've put the loading div, I wanted to have it inside the div with overflow off but I think having it inside each modal screws it up

Comment: You need to post your HTML, showing how the modal and loading divs are related.

Comment: There's only one `id="capa_1"`. The others are `capa_2`, `capa_3`, and `capa_4`.

Comment: Try using `querySelectorAll(".item")`

Comment: I'm linking to .item now as posted, as you can see it works for all the modals but only because the loading div is outside the modals now, previously i had the loading div injected into each modal inside brief_container_modal but even with the javascript linking on .item instead of #capa_1 it only showed on the first modal

Comment: hopefully you can see it, I've put the site host in dev mode so you should have the latest versions

Comment: What happened to the original question? Now your question shows the same code as my answer. How is anyone supposed to know what I was correcting?

Comment: I can't think of a reason why it doesn't work. What happens if you put `console.log()` in the event listener functions, do you see it when you click on any of the items?

Comment: I added that after the first reply, it's not been linked to #capa_1 since I initially posted the question, my question was to find out why it wasn't displaying on the other 2 modals and it still isn't the way I wanted to have it as described in the question, I didn't think it made sense either the way it is should of worked inside the modals the same as it does outside them.

Comment: The location of the loading DIV shouldn't matter, since it uses absolute positioning.

Comment: I've moved the loading div to where it I had it when I set overflow:hidden to brief_container_modal and it removed the overflow of the loading screen as if it was inside the modal, but as it is it didn't work on the 2 other modals, dw if you can't figure it out doesn't have to be inside the modal with overflow hidden just would prefer it

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the problem. The loading DIV doesn't need to be connected to the modals in any way, it just overlays over the whole page, right?

Comment: I wanted it to be inside the modal; so it looks like the content of the modal is loading but not the whole page, the code currently in my question would make it so it replicates the problem, will add the last of the css so that it can be fully re-created.

Comment: Put a loading DIV inside each modal, and use `event.target.querySelector(".loading")` to find the one in that DIV.

Comment: Thanks will try it on the dev url and let you know